# Multiplying within 2D array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to get the product of a permutation of an array:

```
orig_arr = (89..99).to_a

perm = [[89, 90], [89, 91], [89, 92], [89, 93]...]

need = [[8010], [8099], [8188]...]
```

My best guess was to enumerate, but `reduce` doesn't function within `each`:

```
perm.each{|set| set.reduce(:*)}
```

Why doesn't this work? And, is it better to not create a 2D array, and go with a hash or matrix to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it work by using [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) instead of `each`:

```
orig_arr = (89..99).to_a
orig_arr.permutation(2).map { |set| [set.reduce(:*)] }
# => [[8010], [8099], [8188], [8277], [8366], [8455], . . . ]]
```

Comment: @K M Rakibul Islam thank you, that does the trick. I will study-up on #map.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the second application as well. #map is clearly something I need to get very familiar with. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, it's very useful and powerful. You are most welcome :)

Comment: There's no need for `.to_a`. That's because  `orig_arr.permutation(2) #=> #<Enumerator: [89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]:permutation(2)> `  is an instance of the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html), which includes the module [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html) (where `map` resides) and implements the method `each`. Also, it's more Ruby-like to chain rather than defining the temporary variable `perm`: `orig_arr.permutation(2).map { |set| [set.reduce(:*)] }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are right. I have updated my answer. Thanks for your valuable feedback once again, appreciate that :-)